# How to relate one table to another in MySQL (with PHPMyAdmin, preferably)

Tags: mysql

How do I relate one column to another column in another table? Would I create a column with the same name in another table?

Comment: What do you mean by "relate".  You don't have to have the column names the same if you want to just perform a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to establish a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship.  I this example, `Main_Table.id` is referenced as a foreign key in `Related.main_table_id`

```
Main_Table:
----------
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
value1 VARCHAR(8),
value2 VARCHAR(8)

Related:
---------
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- The related column doesn't have to have the same name
-- This column references Main_Table
main_table_id INT NOT NULL
-- The FOREIGN KEY constraint enforces the relationship
FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id) REFERENCES Main_Table (id)
```

Additionally, you can enforce the key relationship through deletion and update. If the row in `Main_Table` is deleted or has its `id` changed, you can force the change to cascade through the related table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id) REFERENCES Main_Table (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
-- Or NULL it rather than delete it
FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id) REFERENCES Main_Table (id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

[See the documentation for full details.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want is called a foreign key. Column names are not grokked by the DB for this purpose.